# BEM HTML Byte Size... does it matter?

Tags: html, performance, pagespeed, bem

I’m working within a CMS which has a limit on a include field of 32,000 characters (I can include multiple includes on each page/template).

Using BEM our header/navigation element has blown the 32000 limit which has led me to question BEM and html performance.

My research so far points to it doesn’t matter too much, css performance does but I’m uneasy asking for the limit to be increased. (45000 would be sufficient) but this is loaded on every page before any content.

The number of links are hidden away with a mega drop down menu and has evolved mainly to support seo requests but in time some may be dropped into the footer but for the time being I need to have indexable links within the header.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am running minify / gzip compression at a server level.

Comment: Have you seen the size of jQuery? 45k is nothing. Just make the CSS/JS stuff in a separate, static file, set up `mod_expire` to tell the client it shouldn't download the stuff on every request and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

General suggestions regarding performance in term of bandwidth and parsing:

- Minify all your CSS and JS
- Compress your HTML and send files using gzip
- Leverage browser caching (set your headers) and consider using CDNs for JS/CSS common libraries
- Optimize any images
- Use shorten name convention for your BEM classes
- Analyse your site using tools as [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/) or similar software and incrementally improve your site

Comment: Group the common CSS property : values and use the short BEM naming across.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pay attention to plain text size. Only gziped size matters. And as research shows BEM naming after gzip is almost identical to manually minified classnames.

So you may use BEM without any worries.